# CRM 365 Workflows and importing data file from Excel

Tags: excel, workflow

When designing Workflows you have a chance to indicate how it is triggered.
In my particular case I am interested to detect  changes in the Status Reason and, for specific states, do something. I can use the "After" filed change on the Status Reason or a Wait condition and everything looks to be OK.

The question I have is in the relation to an Excel Export/Import used for bulk operations. In this case the user can change (using Excel) the Status Reason field to a value matching the condition in the workflow. 
Assuming the workflow is Activated at the time of Excel import, does the workflow get triggered for every row imported? 
It might be very inefficient from a timing perspective but for small data sets might be beneficial and acting as a bulk update, which in fact I am looking for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question,

Yes workflow does get triggered every time you Import data using Excel and it matches the criteria for your Workflow.

Workflow run on server side that means, they will trigger every time value changes in Database and matches criteria. You could run your workflow in asynchronous mode and Crm Async job will take care of allocating resources as and when it has capacity. In this way you will not see performance impact when you Import data via Excel.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it is like this.